# Variable has not been initialised

Tags: java

```
public class Color
{
private int red;
private int green;
private int blue;

/**
 * Turns this color into the equivalent gray value.
 */
public void turnGray()
{
    int red = (int)(0.2126*red + 0.7152*green + 0.0722*blue);
    int green = red;
    int blue = red;

}
```

When i try to compile this the program returns variable red might not have been initialised. Why dosn't this code reassign red to the value on the lhs of the equation?

Comment: `int red = 0.2126*red [...]` what do you expect to output when red hasn't been initialized yet?

Comment: If i remove the initial int from all the rhs of the bottom 3 equations it works, but why??

Comment: `private int red;`, at the class level, will default to 0. However, you re-declare `red` as a local variable in your method, which can't be accessed until it's been initialized

Comment: also I think you're confusing your 'right' and 'left' :^) <-- this is left, --> this is right

Comment: Also note that after the required corrections, the value of `red` will be either `1` or `0`. And as a result, so will the values of `green` and `blue` be. At the end, your color will result in either being rgb(0,0,0) or rgb(1,1,1).

Answer (score 1):

```
int red = (int)(0.2126*red + 0.7152*green + 0.0722*blue);
```

In the above line, you are trying to assign a value to `red` based on values of `red`, `green` and `blue`. Since red is not initialized before, you get the error.

In fact, like pointed out in the comments, none of the variables are initialized.

Also, you are re-declaring the variables with the same name within the method. You could change it to something like shown below, but I am not sure about the logic being used. So it is upto your discretion to make the correct changes.

```
public class Color
{
private double red = 1;
private double green = 1;
private double blue = 1;

/**
 * Turns this color into the equivalent gray value.
 */
public void turnGray()
{
    red = 0.2126*red + 0.7152*green + 0.0722*blue;
    green = red;
    blue = red;
}
```

Note that the variable types are changed to `double` since `int` doesn't support fractions.

Answer (score 1):

You are re-declaring the `red`,`green` and `blue` variables as local variables in your method, hiding the instance variables having the same names. A local variable has no default value and can't be accessed before it is initialized.

Since you have instance members with the same names, I'll assume you meant to use them :

```
public void turnGray()
{
    red = (int)(0.2126*red + 0.7152*green + 0.0722*blue);
    green = red;
    blue = red;
}
```

In this code, the instance variables are used. Now, I hope that you initialize these variables in some code you didn't show us. Otherwise they'll have a default value of 0, and will stay zero when you execute `turnGray`.